# Can offences under S5 public order act be racially or religiously aggravated?

Tags: england-and-wales, freedom-of-speech

It is lesser in that it can't be imprisonable, and the criteria for conviction are lower, but can there be any religiously aggravated element of it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Assuming you are talking about [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_5_of_the_Public_Order_Act_1986), the only requirement is that the words / behavior / writing be threatening or abusive.  It doesn't seem to be relevant whether the threatening words were racially or religiously aggravated; it's an offense whether they were or not.  Is there some reason to think otherwise?

Comment: @NateEldredge in E&W certain offences can be "aggravated" - i.e. some other act etc increases their severity and punishment. In this case, use of R&R language etc changes the sentence for a basic s.5 offence from just a fine to up to two years' imprisonment and/or fine.

Comment: @Rick But it is important to note that it is still an absolute requirement to harbour, and apparently to also *demonstrate*, hostility toward *members* of a given racial or religious group, which is to say that as apparently in accordance with section 29J of part 3 POA 1986 as inserted by RRHA2006, it is not criminal to express or promote opposition to a particular belief or system of belief or lack of belief. For example, trumpeting "atheism is degenerate heresy" in front of an atheist convention will not constitute any type of offence under these provisions, at least not based on the

Comment: racial/religious nature of the content of what you're saying.

Comment: Maybe, but if there's no s.5, it can't be R&R aggravated. But I don't see how that's relevant to what I said in reply to Nate's comment *"I'm not sure I understand the question"* by explaining what makes an offence an aggravated offence as per the OP: *"Can offences under S5 public order act be racially or religiously aggravated?"*

Comment: Well, it's not directly relevant to what you said, but it has relevance to the question in two ways: first because it was asked in a series of questions of which the intention was to explore the intersection of these "hate offence" laws with free speech, and specifically the right to relentlessly decree certain religious ideologies and all that stand for. The original context and intention of the question you couldn't have known, but you answered in the slightly surprising affirmative, and more concretely than Tom did below. I wanted to clarify the limit that was especially relevant in line

Comment: with my original intention in asking the question to reassure anyone reading that despite the citation of scary possible custodial sentences, the principle that the original intention had been to explore the legality of remained protected.

Comment: Secondly, it is especially relevant in the context of S5, because while it's been explained to me that police are trained to understand S4 as I'm going to F*ING kill you, S4A as F*** you and S5 as simply F*** F*** F *** (in public, yet - unlike S4 & S4A - without a directed person or group as the target), the fact that undirected public expressions of what may be seen as objectionable or disagreeable could be punished with prison sentences is concerning however, it isn't simply that hatred towards a religion by virtue of being so and thus liable to cause alatm or distress to religious sect

Comment: adherents has been made criminal: one must actually express antipathy toward the adherents of those sects as such rather than the sect itself.

Comment: Not sure if that's made sense or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Section 31](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1998/37/section/31) of the Crime and Disorder Act 1998 makes it an offence to commit an offence under the Public Order Act (either section 4, 4A or 5) that is racially or religiously aggravated. ([Section 28](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1998/37/section/28) defines racial or religious aggravation for the purposes of the CDA offences, and has been interpreted by the Lords in *[R v Rogers](https://publications.parliament.uk/pa/ld200607/ldjudgmt/jd070228/rogers.htm)* [2007] UKHL 8). The [CPS](https://www.cps.gov.uk/legal-guidance/public-order-offences-incorporating-charging-standard) have some legal guidance on s28-31 offences.

As Rick has noted above: the penalty for an aggravated offence can increase from merely a fine to a potential fine along with up to two years' imprisonment.

However, the aggravating provisions seem to remain in accordance with the spirit and substance of s. 29J Public Order Act 1986 in protecting the right of people to criticise or even insult any belief (or lack of belief), as long as hostility is not exhibited towards its adherents on the basis of their subscription to the beliefs.

Comment: But it is important to note that it is still an absolute requirement to harbour, and apparently to also *demonstrate*, hostility toward *members* of a given racial or religious group, which is to say that as in accordance with section 29J of part 3 POA 1986 as inserted by RRHA2006, it is not criminal to express or promote opposition to a particular belief or system of belief or lack of belief. For example, trumpeting "atheism is degenerate heresy" in front of an atheist convention will not constitute any type of offence under these provisions, at least not based on the racial/religious nature

Comment: of the content.